# How to change the value of a certain index of an array field of a document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have an angular app with cloud firestore with the following structure:

```
--nombre
--grupo
--nombre1
--nombre2
--nombre3
--numerocuenta1
--numerocuenta2
--numerocuenta3
--resuelto
  --0: false
  --1: false
  .
  .
  .
  --13: false
```

As you can see, at the end I have an array of boolean (resuelto) which contains 13 elements, I want to change a value of a certain index when an element with the same index is clicked

¿Is there a way to access each index of that array and change its value?

I tried with this:

```
this.taskDoc = this.afs.doc(`tasks/${task`);
this.taskDoc.update(resuelto[0]); <--
```

And this:

```
this.taskDoc.update(resuelto.0); <--
```

Comment: resuelto is an actual array type field in the document?

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand, what do you mean?

Comment: Look at the document in the Firebase console.  Take a screenshot and post it here if you want.  Does it say that the field is of type array?

Comment: Yes, it's an array https://imgur.com/a/aUA5Z

Answer (score 3):

Firestore doesn't support update of individual array elements.  If you have an array and want to change one of its value, you'll have to read the entire array, change the value locally, then write the entire array back.

It might be better for you to model your data as an object rather than an array.  Object properties may be individually updated by calling out the object field [with the dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot do operations on certain elements in an array by index, you can add or remove elements in an array by value using arrayUnion and arrayRemove:

```
doc.update("someField" : FieldValue.arrayUnion("someValue"))
doc.update("someField" : FieldValue.arrayRemove("someValue"))
```

This makes arrays act more like a set then an array but it at least gives you some options. more documentation here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html